# How can I draw four circles in single div element?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble to draw four circles in single div, as I want to create menu using circles.
Please help me to correct code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="circle">
            </li>
            <li class="circle">


            </li>
            <li class="circle">


            </li>
            <li class="circle">


            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
.menu ul {

     list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline;

}
.circle {
    border-radius: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background: #00b4ff;
   margin-left: 75px;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change ur menu li display property to inline-flex.

```
.menu ul {
     list-style-type: none;

}
.menu li {
    display : inline-flex;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #00b4ff;
    margin-left: 15px;


}
```

inline-block also works

Answer (score 2):

```
.menu li {
    display: inline;
}
```

change this into..

```
.menu li {  
    display: inline-block;
}
```

an inline-block will create a block formatting

or you could use

```
.menu li {  
    float:left;
}
```

if your developing for desktop website, be mind that display:inline-flex has poor support in IE 10 below

Answer (score 2):

If you adding labels to your menu items as follows:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="circle">One</li>
        <li class="circle">Two</li>
        <li class="circle">Three</li>
        <li class="circle">Four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS:

```
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    line-height: 140px;
    background: #00b4ff;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

Use `display: inline-block` (as mentioned in previous answers) and you also need to
specify the `line-height` to be the same as `height` and then apply `vertical-align` and `text-align` to center the text.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/UZbTV/

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marc for detail answer.